# C and JNI arraylist

Tags: java, android, c, java-native-interface

```
        jobjectArray ret;
        int i;

        char *data = malloc(3 * sizeof(char *));

        if(data != NULL)  {
            data[0] = "11";
            data[1] = "22";
            data[2] = "33";
        }
        data = realloc(data, 4 * sizeof(char *));
        if(data != NULL)  {
          data[3] = "44";
        }

        jsize len=4;

            ret= (jobjectArray)(*env)->NewObjectArray(env, len,(*env)->FindClass(env, "java/lang/String"),(*env)->NewStringUTF(env, ""));
        LOGE("startxx");

        jstring      str;
            for(i=0;i<len;i++) {
                str = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, data[i] );
                (*env)->SetObjectArrayElement(env, ret, i, str);
            }

        LOGE("startxxx");

        free(data);
        return(ret);
```

I d like to make an arraylist in c, and then from it, create a java jni array, How can I return the correct "11","22","33","44" array from this code?

**warnings:**

**data[0] = "11";:** warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast

**str = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, data[i] );:** warning: passing argument 2 of '(*env)->NewStringUTF' makes pointer from integer without a cast

Comment: Are you want to return an character array from c to java? M I right?

Comment: i d like to return a string array from c to java

Comment: And my below answer is for return char array from c to java..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

data is declared incorrectly. It should be char** instead of char*.